# Dealing with senior bullying

Tags: professionalism, resignation, politics, bullying, harassment

I have recently joined a renowned firm as a consultant. I had high expectations and the salary was also good. But from the first day itself I was treated differently. After few days I became friend of the full time employee here and he told me that there was strict instruction to him to **keep away from consultants**, being in the same team I felt it very ridiculous. Since last month I facing serious offending behaviour from my senior too. I have totally lost interest in office and my motivation level is very low now, I cannot concentrate in office, what should I do?

I have some offers in hand but there is a notice period of two months of my current employers' contract. I am not sure I can survive in this situation for next two months, what to do?

Comment: Always remember, it takes very small man to be a bully.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are feeling mistreated by both your firm (your senior?) and your client (stay away from consultants, etc.)? I would almost agree with Kilisi's answer below.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang I am mistreated by my client, I work on client location and I have to face my senior and I can't get away with it hence all the arguments of ignoring doesn't apply here.

Comment: Your senior is your supervisor from your own firm who is also on-site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked in places that have this mentality.  Consultants are disposable and don't get attached to them.  Basically you are there so they don't have to hire anyone full time and can stop the contract at their choosing.

Also, as you mentioned this is really poor for everyone as you can't progress as a team with discriminating behavior.

**Recommendations**:

1. Be sure you understand the legal terminology for hostile work environment in your country.  Some have one and others seem to even allow physical violence without too much recompense.
2. Discuss with the hiring manager that you feel a hostile work environment is being created by the treatment and you wish to discuss and come to a resolution so that you can best fulfill the contract for the companies benefit regardless of whether you get another contract or not.  Be professional and try to avoid names, but talk of attitudes and specific comments.
3. Try to honor the contract, but get yourself somewhere that the environment leaves you feeling safe and healthy to work at.

Good luck and sorry you are in that environment.

Comment: Should I make these much efforts to remain in such organisation? I talked to my manager but I don't think they can do much as they are running a consultancy and just for one resource they cannot afford to argue with the host company.

Comment: Only you can say how much you can take.  It looks much better on a resume to adhere to the notice and break cleanly, otherwise you might jeopardize your future impression...but if you can't take anymore you can't take anymore.  Check on the legality though cause if you break contract you might not be able to work in the same sector for a competitor for x period of time.

Comment: I have been here since less than 2 months.

Comment: sorry @CodeYogi but that is a choice you will have to make.  Perhaps your consultancy can advise you on the specific contract/company specifics or even swap you to another contract.

Comment: @mutt "consultant" does imply a short term contractor many FTE roles are called consultants

Comment: @Neuromancer Full time implies benefits and company inclusion where FTE is Full TIme Equivalency implying that it could be a consultant and thus bypassing the company benefit and inclusion.  There are tons of FTEs filled by consultants instead of full time hires which may also fill an FTE spot.

Answer (score 3):

As a consultant this shouldn't be allowed to bother you, all you should be doing is concentrating on your tasks and collecting your money.

Most places I work as a consultant I have little to do with the normal staff in terms of socialising. I'm polite but keep my distance. I don't answer to them and I may need to investigate them at some point. In fact I know that many are jealous despite smiling to my face and would not hesitate to stab me in the back. I get paid more than them and am outside their authority hierarchy. The longer you work there the more respect you will get, but you will always be different.

Your situation might be different in details but in general this should not be a concern for a professional consultant.

Comment: You are basically saying don't worry about it.

Comment: But what if I am aksed why I am late to office or which doctor you met when you took off yesterday? or because of you others code are breaking.

Comment: Why are you late? Why is your code breaking others? Consultants don't have the cushion of full time employees, they need to watch their backs at all times and have a solid paper trail on everything.

Comment: Who told the statements are correct, these are the allegations which I obviously don't like. Mind it I told she is a senior and not Manager or VP and both of them have no issues with me, the only dilemma is they don't sit at my office location.

Comment: Consultants don't have to like anything, they just need to cover their backs and collect their money. I've tried explaining this 3 different ways, perhaps you're not cut out for the job.

Comment: you are making assumptions about the status of consultants

Comment: @Kilisi I don't know what type of work environment you have in mind but I my case I have to sit at client location and I have to work as a time, senior I am talking about belongs to the host company. I can't work in isolation.